# Open link in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, popup

I might be tired but I just can't figure out what the problem is. What I'm trying to do is open a link in a popup window. I got this code below working before but I removed it.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com','popup','width=600,height=700,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0'); return false">About</a>
```

However, it stopped working now when I put it back. I even got it working on jsFiddle so I'm at lost on what to do. I'm assuming something must be blocking it from running?

The code is short and simple so I figured someone here might have an idea what could cause this.

**EDIT:** Sorry I should have thought of it. I guess I should sleep. Anyway here's a demo-website where I reproduced the problem http://testmycode.tumblr.com/ The problem is the "About" link, pressing it returns nothing.

Comment: `I even got it working on jsFiddle` Then you should show us your other code.

Comment: What other code? The problem is I have no idea what would cause this behaviour so I'm looking for suggestion, someone who knows scripts/functions that could block popup links.

Comment: Isn't the code in the question a part of the whole HTML document?

Comment: If it works in jsFiddle then the issue must be in the part other than the code you posted here.

Comment: Am I supposed to post the whole HTML document and let you review it line by line..?

Comment: At least you can post an example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I'll post a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems like somewhere in your code you have changed the `window` variable to a custom function. When you try to call `window.open` <sup><sub>(more specifically, `document.window.open`)</sub></sup>, the method `open` simply doesn't exist in the function `window`, which causes it to throw an error.

Check this out:

[image]

You <s>somewhere</s> changed it to a function by doing `document.window = ...`.

It's MooTools 1.2.4 which changed it:

[image]

---

To fix it, simply using an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) and problem solved! (Inline codes are bad practice anyway.)

```
<a class="about">About</a>

$(".about")attr("href", "#").click(function(e){
    window.open(...);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that a script code from jotform.com caused the problem. Ah okay, I always went for inline codes because it saves a bit work but I'll try to do that, thanks again!

Comment: @TonyFire - Your welcome. PS: Actually you would find doing maintenance on event listeners are sometimes easier than inline. :)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you shared works when I append it to the page we are at, in Google Chrome. Which makes me wonder which browser you are having the trouble in. So I would encourage you to try the snippet you shared in Google Chrome, and if it works there then you will know it is a browser specific kind of bug, in which case I would try adding a semicolon after `return false`.

Comment: I don't think it's a browser problem. The semicolon didn't change it. I added a demo-website as suggested. Should have thought of that.